# Dynamically Select columns based on column value

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Hello and thanks for taking some time to help with my question.

I am trying to create a conditional if statement using laravel eloquent model.

A sample of my code is like:

```
$query = DB::table('example')->select('test1',
             DB::raw('IF(test2 = "myText" , test2, FALSE) AS test2_Alias'),
             DB::raw('IF(test2 = "myText" , test3, FALSE) AS test3_Alias')
         )->first();
```

The condition works fine and i retrieve my results but i need a different thing. Is there a way to remove completely the false statement so my column name does not appear at all?

So my output will be:

```
 1 array field if `test2` text is not `myText` (test1)
 3 array fields if `test2` test is `myText`    (test1,test2,test3)
```

`Case-when` did not work either for that because still there is a fallback there.

`Union` also does not fit me because i need to have the same number of columns in my select statements which is not something i want as explained above.

Of course as a last solution i can always retrieve all the columns and apply the logic in PHP side but i was hoping that there might be a Mysql Solution for my issue.

***Edit to add more info***

What i am trying to achieve is based on the value of 1 field to select more columns or exclude them from my output.

Comment: Yes.. Do it by "hand" in a PHP-loop.

Comment: Yeah i was afraid of that actually cause there are many fields and i will have to `unset` them and my code will look a bit "ugly" or i will have to run a query and based on that modify my select on the second query.

 Thank you for your input really appreciate the help.

Comment: SQL always returns a table. You can not have 3 columns in one row, and 2 columns in another row. That wouldn't be a table. You can play around with JSON - But I tell you - It's much simpler to do remove "empty" properties in PHP.

Comment: But i will always have 1 row that's why i used first. I just want based on field value to select specific columns.

Comment: Well.. still - The number of returned rows is determined by the query, before any data is read from the table. You would need to run two queries - and that doesn't make sense. More code and more work for the server.

Comment: People from other questions come to angry-downvote ... I don't get that ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to solve it on SQL side. But you will still need to use PHP to write that crazy query dynamically. Or worse - You will write program code in SQL. While post processing in PHP is quite simple:

```
// $row = DB::..

$row = (object)[ // result from DB
    'field1' => 'value1',
    'field2' => null,
    'field3' => 'value3'
];

foreach (get_object_vars($row) as $key => $val) {
    if ($val === null) {
        unset($row->{$key});
    }
}
```

That are effectively three lines of quite simple code. The result from `var_export($row)`:

```
stdClass::__set_state(array(
   'field1' => 'value1',
   'field3' => 'value3',
))
```

As you see, the field with NULL is removed.

Even better: keep your query simple and just select `test2` instead of `IF(test2 = "myText" , test2, FALSE) AS test2_Alias`. And then "dynamically" create `test2_Alias` if needed:

```
if ($row->test2 == 'myText') {
    $row->test2_Alias = $row->test2;
}
```

Yes - that's boring. Nothing fancy. But you will love simple code, when you try to fix some bugs.

#### Update

From our chat:

> test1,test2,test3 are columns    let me explain better in code I want
>   to have:
>
> Select(test1)
>
> select(test1,test2,test3) but the second select should happen only if
>   test2 has a specific value

Assuming your "specific value" is stored in `$specificValue`.

```
$row = DB::('example')->select('test1, test2, test3')->first();
if ($row->test2 != $specificValue) {
    unset($row->test2, $row->test3);
}
```

That's it. IMHO it's better than executing two queries like:

```
$test2 = DB::('example')->value('test2');
$select = ($test2 == $specificValue) 
    ? 'test1, test2, test3'
    : 'test1';
$row = DB::('example')->select($select)->first();
```

Comment: The only issue on what i try to achieve is that i need the fields no matter their value. So for my case the Null field should be there cause i need to know the data of each field even if it is empty or null so i don't want to remove actually. I think that for my problem the solution would be in 2 steps. 1 check if the column-row field has the static value i need to check  2 run the select statement i want with the fields i need

Comment: That's in your question. "Is there a way to remove completely the false statement so my column name does not appear at all?" - I just replaced FALSE with NULL.

Comment: LOL.. that's the only question in your post :-)

Comment: The issue is that based on the value of 1 field i will  select more than 1 rows. I put a small example i will edit the code in my question

Comment: You should be more consistent with what you write - "But i will always have 1 row".

Comment: But it is 1 row. test1,test2,test3 are columns.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189389/discussion-between-pr1nc3-and-paul-spiegel).